# How to hide ASIAuthenticationDialog screen after entering proper proxy credentials in iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Can anyone who is using ASIHTTP classes for Proxy Authentication.

If yes then please help me out.
I am facing one issue on ASIAuthenticationDialog which appears in iPhone and after entering proxy user name and password its working. but when we do the same in iPad its window is not getting disappear.

Thanks,